# (yet another) problem with mapped drive via the command line

Tags: nant, startup, ccnet-config, mapped-drive, localsystem

I know, I know. There are a million threads everywhere talking about problems with mapped drives. I've ready many of them but I still can's seem to wrap my head around this problem or come to a solution.

I have a build server/continuous integration server (Win 2003 running CruiseControl.NET) that listens to our source control server. When a change is detected, the build server gets the new code, compiles it, tests it and if successful, copies the files to one of our web servers. There are 6 web servers - 3 Windows 2003 boxes, 3 LAMP boxes. Each OS has a separate development, staging and production box. All 6 web servers are mapped to a different drive on the build server. I have a Windows start-up script that calls a few "NET USE" commands that set the stage for the deployments.

CCNET is the service that listens to SVN. However, CCNET calls NAnt to perform all of the actual processing and tasks (compilation, testing, copying).

When I map the drives manually and run the NAnt scripts manually, everything works beautifully. When the startup script maps the drives and CCNET triggers the NAnt, the drives are nowhere to be found. I think the problem has something to do with user accounts. CCNET runs under the LOCAL SYSTEM account. I don't know what account the startup script runs under. Obviously manual execution runs under my account.

The weirdest part is that at certain points in the past, everything was working great. I am not sure what changed. How can I get the mapped drives to be visible to all users and services? (Also, any other critique of any part of this setup/process is welcome)

Comment: Maybe I should simplify the situation. I have several mapped drives that are accessible to my personal user account but inaccessible to the LOCAL SYSTEM account. Ultimately, I dont care if they are accessible to my account, but I NEED the LOCAL SYSTEM account to be able to access these mapped network drives. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem definitely was with user accounts. The drives were mapped under different accounts than the account CCNET was running on. Once I finally straightened everything out and got it running on the LOCAL SYSTEM account everything worked fine.